# Return entity that has highest/lowest value in the related entity

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, lambda, navigation-properties

How to look for the highest or lowest value from the related entity?
I was trying to use LINQ/lambda with a navigation property but run into a NullReferenceException.

```
Dim e As employee = Me.employees
       .OrderBy(Function(x) x.car.car_age.GetValueOrDefault(1000))
       .First()

If e IsNot Nothing Then Return e.car.car_age
```

With data, the case example

employee

```
id  name   car_id
1   John   1
2   Mark   2
3   Steve  3
```

car

```
id  car_age
1   15
2   [Null]
3   8
4   19
5   3
```

employee and car 1-to-1 relationship.

When looking for highest value, I need to get employee "John" from the query.
When looking for lowest value, I need "Steve".
car_age can also be null in the database.

Berfore calling the above, the entities were retrieved from the database using:

```
Dim query = From e In _context.employees.Include("car")
            Select e
```

Comment: What's the `NullReferenceException`'s `StackTrace` value?

Comment: at MyNS.MyModel.company._Lambda$__41(employee x) in C:/Temp...
at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at MyNS.MyModel.company.get_OldestCar()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace suggests you have employees without cars. Are you certain the only data you have is the one you shown in your post?

What happens if you try this instead:

```
Dim e As employee = Me.employees
    .Where(Function(x) x.car IsNot Nothing)
    .OrderBy(Function(x) x.car.car_age.GetValueOrDefault(1000))
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

Does the app still crashes? If not then there's your problem: some employee just don't have a car.

Comment: With that I get InvalidOperationExceltion (Sequence contains no elements). Its possible and acceptable that employee doesn't have a car and car_id can be Null.

Comment: @user2143213 Ah, then *none* of your employee have cars now it seems! :) I edited my answer, have a look.

Comment: In the failed case, yes, none of the employees had a car. FirstOrDefault was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want something like:

```
Dim e As employee = Me.employees
   .Where(Function(x) x.car.car_age IsNot Nothing)
   .OrderBy(Function(x) x.car.car_age.GetValueOrDefault(1000))
   .First()
```

Comment: In VB.NET this works: Dim e As employee = Me.employees.Where(Function(x) x.car IsNot Nothing).OrderBy(Function(x) x.car.car_age.GetValueOrDefault(1000)).First() but if I use Where(Function(x) x.car.car_age IsNot Nothing then I run into the same NullReferenceException.

Comment: ...but won't work if all the car_id's are Null's -> InvalidOperationException (Sequence contains no elements)